# Network Image is giving error even after using image error builder

Tags: flutter, image, dart, http, flutter-layout

I am making a podcast application in a flutter, I am trying to load images in the simple layout where I am using the FadeInImage widget and populating the image from JSON as a List (currently do not have a model because of testing). The code is something like this.

```
 FadeInImage(
                          image: image != null
                              ? NetworkImage(image)
                              : const NetworkImage(
                                  'https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png'),
                          placeholder: const AssetImage("assets/chimp.png"),
                          imageErrorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                            return Image.asset('assets/chimp.png',
                                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth);
                          },
                          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                        )
```

In the above code, the image has the path to that image. I have created a separate image error builder so that if the imageurl returns any error so it gets handled

The error is not even coming in the debug output so here are the images of the error

[image]

[image]

The error is coming in line 120 of network_image_io.dart file.

And the debug console is showing the following error. I checked all the answers but most of them are saying just use errorBuilder but even after implementing the imageErrorBuilder I am facing the same issue.
Can anyone please help with this?

[image]

Comment: Please add your pubspec.yaml and have added internet permission in the manifest file

Comment: I already have internet permission.

Comment: Can you please show where you assign the value of image because without that it's working charm.

Answer (score 0):

First You Give **Internet Permission** for an app that's why a 404 error shows that can't assess the image.

Comment: Thanks for helping but the 404 error which I am talking about is on the API side some image url are not being upload on the api server.